# GMAT. How to get rid of the $\pi$ in this answer? Rates and cylinder problem.

Tags: geometry, word-problem

> When a cylindrical tank is filled with water at a rate of 22 cubic
>   meters per hour, the level of water in the tank rises at a rate of 0.7
>   meters per hour. Which of the following best approximates the radius
>   of the tank in meters?

The choices:
- $\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}$
- $\sqrt{10}$
- 4
- 5
- 10

So I started off with this.

The rate is 22 $m^3$/hr and so after 1 hour, there will be 22 $m^3$ in the tanka and the height will be 0.7m

So...

22 = $\pi$ * $r^2$ * 7/10

$\frac {220}{7}$ = $\pi$ * $r^2$

Now what?

Comment: Estimating $\pi$ to be 3 would be a decent start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably know that $\frac{22}7$ is approximately $\pi$, so your last equation is approximately $10\pi=\pi r^2$; now just cancel $\pi$.